# Convert MongoDB collection to Json file and read from the same Json file in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am trying to convert mongodb collection to json file and later on load the same Json file data to another MongoDB collection. The collection has around 60,000 rows. I have written the following code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson import json_util

with open("collections/review.json", "w") as f:
    l = list(reviews_collection.find())  
    json.dump(json.dumps(l,default=json_util.default),f,indent = 4)

# reviews_collection_bkp.remove()
reviews_collection_bkp.remove()
with open("collections/review.json") as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
            data = json.loads(line)
            reviews_collection_bkp.insert({
                 "reviewId": data["reviewId"],
                 "business": data["business"],
                 "text": data["text"],
                 "stars": data['stars'],
                 "votes":data["votes"]
             })
print reviews_collection_bkp.find().count()
```

`review_collection` is the collection I want to write in a Json file names `review.json` and later on want to read from the same file to insert data into a MongoDB collection. But I think the code is not able to create a proper json file. Because upon reading the same file produces the following error:

```
    "reviewId": data["reviewId"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Why the Json file created is in incorrect format ?

This is the sample output of `line` and `data`:

```
"[{\"votes\": {\"funny\": 0, \"useful\": 0, \"cool\": 0}, \"business\": \"wqu7ILomIOPSduRwoWp4AQ\", \"text\": \"Went for breakfast on 6/16/14. We received very good service and meal came within a few minutes.Waitress could have smiled more but was friendly. \\nI had a Grand Slam... it was more than enough food. \\nMeal was very tasty... We will definitely go back. \\nIt is a popular Denny's.\", \"reviewId\": \"0GS3S7UsRGI4B7ziy4cd7Q\", \"stars\": 4, \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5711d16fe396f81fcb51dc73\"}},...]

[{"votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0}, "business": "wqu7ILomIOPSduRwoWp4AQ", "text": "Went for breakfast on 6/16/14. We received very good service and meal came within a few minutes.Waitress could have smiled more but was friendly. \nI had a Grand Slam... it was more than enough food. \nMeal was very tasty... We will definitely go back. \nIt is a popular Denny's.", "reviewId": "0GS3S7UsRGI4B7ziy4cd7Q", "stars": 4, "_id": {"$oid": "5711d16fe396f81fcb51dc73"}}......]
```

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the `.json` file ? Your `data` is a **string**, thats what the error says

Comment: Please post a sample of `line`, and `data`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that each line of the file is a valid json?

I think that this is a correct approach:

```
with open("collections/review.json") as dataset:
    data = json.loads(dataset)
    for line in data:
        reviews_collection_bkp.insert({
             "reviewId": line['reviewId'],
             ...
         })
```

If this doesn't work, try print the json file generated, for know how to decode.

Comment: json file is too big to print . I have added the sample line and data output in the question itself.

Comment: Try by this way:

`data[0]['reviewId']`

Each line is a list, and the first item is a dict. Decode the line, and then access the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is a list of dictionaries you need traverse it.

```
for line in dataset:
    data = json.loads(line)
    for doc in data:
         reviews_collection_bkp.insert({
                 "reviewId": data["reviewId"],
                 "business": data["business"],
                 "text": data["text"],
                 "stars": data['stars'],
                 "votes":data["votes"]
             })
```

Comment: still getting the same result.

Comment: `json.loads(dataset)` is throwing `TypeError: expected string or buffer` and after calling `'json.load()` it throws string index error.

Comment: @triple.s Is your `data` type `str` ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a list ?

Comment: Yes.. thats why I doubt that the Json file itself is not created in a valid format !

Comment: just use `json.dump(l,f)` and `json.load(dataset)` for loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109346/discussion-between-dnit13-and-triple-s).